# querying and posting to mysql from php. Serialize array and save it to database or create about 15 different columns?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

The data will consist of 1 or 2 digit numbers and I can either make a (to my experience) a hectic looking database full of all the primary data plus these extra 15 columns or I could use the serialization function on the array which I'm already going to be keeping these numbers to save room and tidy up the database.

**Questions you may have:**

- Every query that changes one of these numbers will affect the rest of them.
- I am using php right now along with possibly javascript and ajax, however I will eventually rewrite the project fully or partially in python and or C.  So that serialization function may make things a bit sticky there...
- The information in the database is going to be read and written to by 2 individuals using separate internet connections.

If you need an example it would play out as follows:

```
row in database is created by php. 
user_1 && user_2 read. 
user_1 writes. 
user_1 && user_2 read. 
user_2 writes. 
user_1 && user_2 read.
```

And so on...  next user_1 would write again.

So if anyone could please give me any assistance..  I am majorly concerned about whether mysql is the best choice for this project; it is basically my only free option.  And to serialize or not to serialize..? (given my personal situation).

Thank you all so much in advanced.

Comment: See the DBA stack exchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23514/what-should-i-use-a-string-or-15-integer-fields for a very similar question.  Are you always going to have exactly those 15 fields?  Would normalising the values out to another table make sense for your application?

Comment: Not too much the left overdata is very minimal (after taking those 15 fields out).  Thanks for the link I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL  has great  array support.  You make an  column that is  an array of integer